# Export Powershell command to Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, get

I have the following command

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |%{"Total Physical Memory: {0}KB`nFree Physical Memory : {1}KB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2}KB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3}KB" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize, $_.freephysicalmemory, $_.totalvirtualmemorysize, $_.freevirtualmemory}
```

I want to export the above output to an excel file. I have:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |%{"Total Physical Memory: {0}KB`nFree Physical Memory : {1}KB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2}KB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3}KB" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize, $_.freephysicalmemory, $_.totalvirtualmemorysize, $_.freevirtualmemory} | Select-Object VisibleMem, FreeMem, VirtualMem,FreeVirtualMem | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

This doesn't output anything besides titles of columns.I am looking for the output in each column. Any help?

Comment: `This doesn't output what I need` - so what _do_ you need? Please be more specific, how is this not working?

Comment: I need output in an excel file. There is not output shown with the above

Comment: This bit: ***"Total Physical Memory: {0}KB`nFree Physical Memory : {1}KB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2}KB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3}KB" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize, $_.freephysicalmemory, $_.totalvirtualmemorysize, $_.freevirtualmemory}*** creates a string object that you then pass to this bit: ***Select-Object VisibleMem, FreeMem, VirtualMem,FreeVirtualMem***. The string object does not have any of those properties so nothing actually gets passed to this bit: ***Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture***.

Comment: You need to decide exactly what you want in the CSV and build that in the Select portion using expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're throwing away the object with its properties when you create the the strings in your `Foreach-Object` loop so you don't have anything to export to csv anymore.
2. The property names in `Select-Object` doesn't exist. You can't make up column names (without using calculated properties/columns, see sample of this below).

Try this to output the data:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |
Select-Object TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory, TotalVirtualMemorySize, FreeVirtualMemory |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

If you need different column-names:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |
Select-Object @{n="VisibleMem";e={$_.TotalVisibleMemorySize}}, @{n="FreeMem";e={$_.FreePhysicalMemory}}, @{n="VirtualMem";e={$_.TotalVirtualMemorySize}}, @{n="FreeVirtualMem";e={$_.FreeVirtualMemory}} |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

If you need to write the text to the screen (for the user to see) while also saving them you would need to use `Write-Host` and remember to let the object passthrough to the next cmdlet in the pipeline:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |
ForEach-Object {
    #Write to screen
    Write-Host ("Total Physical Memory: {0}KB`nFree Physical Memory : {1}KB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2}KB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3}KB" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize, $_.freephysicalmemory, $_.totalvirtualmemorysize, $_.freevirtualmemory);
    #Throw the original object to the next cmdlet in the pipeline
    $_ 
} |
Select-Object TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory, TotalVirtualMemorySize, FreeVirtualMemory |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: I think tee-object might have a place for your last example as well.

Comment: He wanted to export to CSV and `tee-object` only writes to textfile or variable AFAIK so I couldn't think of an easy way to use it this time. :-)